# Ошибка "Cannot find executable for CFBundle (CertUIFramework.axbundle (not loaded))"

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios7, iphone

В Xcode 5, при тестировании на iOS 7 эмуляторе в каждом проекте выскакивает ошибка по типу:

> `Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0x8c7c2f0 </Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/CertUIFramework.axbundle> (not loaded)`

Покопавшись на офф форуме, и на других сервисах нашел из советов только

1. Переустановить Xcode
2. Очистить содержимое эмулятора и почистить проект (Clean -> Cmd+Shift+k)

Ни первое, ни второе не помогло решить проблему. При том, проблема появляется даже в чистых, шаблонных проектах.

Кто сталкивался уже с этим, есть способы решения?

Comment: Вопрос как Вы переустанавливали Xcode. Если просто удалили из Аппликаций - то возможно хвосты остались. Но попробуйте в меню iOS Simulator -> Reset content and settings...

Comment: Ресет симулятора делал. Помогает ровно до следующего запуска.

Comment: Нужно тогда удалить полностью Xcode со всеми потрохами и установить начисто все. Что-то где-то при обновлении не срослось. Только удалять через терминал.

Comment: Не подскажите как?)
"sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all"
не работает :)

Comment: /Developer это сейчас /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer

Comment: "sudo /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all" выдает "sudo: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools: command not found"

Comment: Тогда удалите его обычным способом. Удалите инсталляционный пакет, если он есть и проверьте, удалились ли все файлы из директории Xcode.app. По идее ее не должно существовать. Потом установите его снова через App Store.

Comment: У меня при обновлении с четверки тоже возникли проблемы. Удалил Xcode и Simulator AppCleaner'ом и заново поставил из аппстора. Все стало нормально. Ну и не забудьте пойти в Preferences -> Downloads и установить все что там есть

Comment: все равно толку ноль =( мб это как то связано с OS Mavericks